# C# AutoMapper Custom Resolver based on property names

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

I'm using **AutoMapper** (v6.1.1) to map some Entity objects to DTO objects that will be returned by a **Web Api** REST Web Service in **.NET 4.6.2**.

Now I manually set my mappings like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize((config) =>
{
    config.CreateMap<SignBook, sdk.SignBook>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.DocumentId, conf => conf.MapFrom(obj => obj.Document.Id))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.UserId, conf => conf.MapFrom(obj => obj.User.Id))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.DeviceId, conf => conf.MapFrom(obj => obj.Device.Id))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.SignTypeId, conf => conf.MapFrom(obj => obj.SignType.Id))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.StateId, conf => conf.MapFrom(obj => obj.State.Id))
        .ReverseMap();
});
```

But, as you can see, all the Properties of DTO object is simply named like the **Entity name + "Id"** suffix (e.g.: `Document.Id` in Entity to `DocumentId` in DTO).

Since I've many Entities to map, I'd like to create a mapping rule for AutoMapper (so create a Custom Resolver) that will do this automatically.
Is it possible somehow?

Is there also some best practices when you need to do something like that? So what I want to do is map Entities objects to DTO objects. My Entities are NHibernate objects that has many realtions with each other and also uses Lazy Loading, so I can't push them back directly to Web Api method results to be serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper supports [Flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) by default. All you need is simple mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<SignBook, sdk.SignBook>().ReverseMap();
});
```

and starting from AutoMapper 6.1 [Unflattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening) is also supported.

---

Flattening:

```
var entity = new SignBook { new Document { Id = 42 } };
var dto = Mapper.Map<sdk.SignBook>(entity);
```

gives you

```
{
  "DocumentId": 42
}
```

Unflattening:

```
var dto = new sdk.SignBook { DocumentId = 42 };
var entity = Mapper.Map<SignBook>(dto);
```

gives

```
{
  "Document": {
    "Id": 42
  }
}
```

Comment: I really didn't know it was so simply!